# read everything even when a signal is sent in c program

Tags: c, signals

I am stuck in a BIG problem.

I am trying to understand signals in c and how to bypass them.

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<errno.h>

void    ft_hand(int a)
{
    (void)a;
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_IGN);
    char buf[1000];

    while(read(0, buf, 1))
        write(1, buf, 1);
}
```

It's a simple code where you read what I actually type and write it in the screen.
The problem is when I do the signal for SIGQUIT (ctrl + ) after having typing some word

```
123^\456
456
```

In this example, I type "123" and send the signal and retype 456 and press enter.
It only shows me the number after the signal (456).
I need to get everything to show, but I don't know how to do it .
I already tried to save it in a string by remalloc but it's not working. It looks like read only sees what is after the signal.

I have been stuck for 2 days looking at the doc of signal but it gives me headache.

Thanks for any help you can give me. Have a good day.

Comment: Your read() can retuurn -1, 0, or 1. You did not check the -1 case. Also: the terminal-driver is involved. Try sending the signal from a different process (terminal) And: you probably get a EINTR or EAGAIN from the read() -->> check errno.

Comment: Maybe on your system the behaviour of `signal()` is equivalent to invoking `sigaction()` with the `SA_RESTART` option — which causes system calls to continue after an interrupt as if nothing has happened.  That's permitted, but not mandated, by the C and POSIX standards.

Comment: The programme keep going is good , it should not stop after I send Ctrl+\ .But I need to catch what is before the Ctrl +\ , how do you do that ?:/

Comment: Are you on Unix or Linux? Try the shell command `stty noflsh` .